# Reseller API can't list Subscriptions with readonly scope

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm developing a program to control our customers, using Google Apps Reseller API.

To not give too much access to the system, I'm trying to use the readonly scopes.

Trying to list the subscriptions sending

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/apps/reseller/v1/subscriptions
```

with a token generate with the scope

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.order.readonly
```

gives me the error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403, 
    "message": "Forbidden", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global", 
        "message": "Forbidden", 
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But if I use the scope

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.order
```

(not a readonly scope) it works.

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it looks like a bug.  We will triage internally.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the readonly scope does not work.  You'll need to use the read/write scope.